# Why is Wrong answer Uva : Factovisors

Tags: c++, algorithm

For the problem [10139 - Factovisors](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1080) on UVa Online Judge, 2 numbers `n` and `m` are given, and we need to check whether `m` divides `n!`.

I use the algorithm:

1. Generate primes till const number
2. Take `m` and get its primes factor
3. For each prime in `m`'s factors, calculate `getpower` function for `n` and compare them

I test different cases it give me also Wrong Answer, any suggestion?

Here's my code:

```
bool Factovisor (int n, int m) {

/* Special Cases */ 

    if(n==0 && m!=1 ) 
        return false;
    else if(n==0&&m==1) 
        return true;
    else if(m==0) 
        return false;
    else if(m==n||m==1) 
        return true;
    else if (n >= m)
        return true;
    else {

        vector <factores> factores_in_m; 
        int index = 0;
        int k=m;
/* first I generate all primes in primes vector */

        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            if (primes[i] > k) {
                break;

            } else {
/* factores is struct contain the prime and count*/

                factores f = {primes[i], 0};
                while (k % primes[i] == 0) {
                    f.count += 1;
                    k = k / primes[i];
                }

                if (f.count) {
                    factores_in_m.push_back(f);
                }
            }
        }

        if (k > 1) { 
            if (n < k) {
                return false;
            } else {
                factores f;
                f.prime= k;
                f.count =1;
                factores_in_m.push_back(f);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < factores_in_m.size(); i++) {
            if (factores_in_m[i].count - get_powers(n, factores_in_m[i].prime) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

int get_powers (int n, int p) {
    int result = 0, power = p;
    while (power <= n) { 
        result += n / power;
        power =power* p;
    }
    return result;
}

bool isPrime (int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void get_prime () {
    for (int i = 2; i < maxn0; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `get_powers` implemented? Are you absolutely sure that your prime generation is correct?

Comment: here you are the code of it 
` 
int get_powers (int n, int p) {

 int result = 0, power = p;

 while (power <= n) {

  result += n / power;

  power =power* p;

 }

 return result;

}
`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your prime generation is faulty, but certainly your `get_powers` implementation is susceptible to `int` overflow.

```
int get_powers (int n, int p) {
    int result = 0, power = p;
    while (power <= n) { 
        result += n / power;
        power =power* p;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If `int` is, as it usually is, a 32-bit wide type, for primes larger than 46341 the computation `power = power * p;` overflows the first time it is done. That can lead to wrong results, for example

```
get_powers(10000000, 131071)
```

returns 52 if the overflow behaviour is wraparound modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, but the correct result would be 76. Now, since `m` is smaller than 2<sup>31</sup>, this particular one wouldn't hurt, since `m` cannot be divisible by 131071². But under the wraparound behaviour,

```
get_powers(1000000, 699733) = -2192
```

is negative, so for `n = 1000000` and `m = 2*699733` for example, you would wrongly conclude that `n!` isn't divisible by `m`.

To avoid the possible overflow, only divide by `p`,

```
int get_powers(int n, int p) {
    int result = 0;
    n /= p;
    do {
        result += n;
        n /= p;
    }while(n > 0);
    return result;
}
```

---

From the comments:

> I edited to add my functions to get primes till constant number "maxn0" – userG 2 hours ago
>
> What value have you chosen for maxn0? – Daniel Fischer 2 hours ago
>
> `maxn0 = 10000`

That value is too small.

With the primes to 10000, you are only guaranteed to correctly factorise numbers not exceeding 10<sup>8</sup> (well, since the next prime is 10007, numbers smaller than `10007² = 100140049`), but the limit is given as 2<sup>31</sup>, which is much larger.

Whenever a number `m` is given with two (not necessarily distinct) prime factors larger than 10000, you will not correctly factorise that, and that will usually lead to a wrong answer.

You need all primes ≤ √(2<sup>31</sup>-1), that is all primes `< 46340` to obtain the correct factorisation of all admissible `m`.

Comment: thanks It gives a correct solutions at the big numbers as you mentioned but unluckiness it's also gives me Wrong Answer may be from another thing

Comment: The next suspect is `primes`. I may be overlooking something, but apart from the overflow possibility in `get_powers`, what you have posted looks correct.

Comment: I edited to  add my functions to get primes till constant number "maxn0"

Comment: What value have you chosen for `maxn0`?

Comment: thanks For your Help and your answer and comments. Now it's Done. yes it was a wrong answer with **maxn0 = 10000** when I change it to **maxn0 = 50000** it's run ok

Comment: @userG Just updated with that, with a short explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: wrong answer due to a misanderstanding of the question.

9 divides 7! but your algorithm will answer false because `get_powers(7, 3) == 0` and 3 is a factor of 9.

It is not your implementation that is wrong but your algorithm.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh It is the answer to the question, why should it be a comment?

Comment: No, with the implementation of `get_powers` posted in the comments, `get_powers(7,3)` returns 2, as it should.

Comment: You didn't explain why it is wrong and how to resolve it. At most, you only give a failing test case, which I think OP can find, since he mentioned that he tested already.

Comment: @DanielFischer indeed I thought the `get_powers` function does what its name suggests but it doesn't according to the code in the comments.

Comment: Well, it gets the power of `p` that divides `n!`. In this setting, the name is okay, although I see how you got the wrong idea.

Comment: no the result of ` get_powers(7, 3) == 2 ` and my code give the answer that "9 divides 7! "